# Jaxb marshalling failing with ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

I have compile my xsd doc and begun to write junit tests for my wrapper.

When I call marshal I get the stack trace below. I was surprised to have an eclipse class not found. (org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory)

What am I missing from my classpath? Or is there something else I am missing?

I am running eclipse indigo 3.7.2.

My classpath include the following jars:
jaxb-api.jar, jaxb-impl.jar, jaxb-xjc.jar, jaxb1impl.jar, jsr173_1.0_api.jar,

My compiler is set to java 6 compatability.

```
1 [main] WARN com.bellsouth.snt.cnmp.dao.csp.CspInputMarshaller  - Cannot marshal xml data
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory not found
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.bellsouth.snt.cnmp.dao.csp.CspInputMarshaller.jaxbMarshal(CspInputMarshaller.java:69)
at com.bellsouth.snt.cnmp.dao.csp.CspInputMarshaller.marshal(CspInputMarshaller.java:46)
at com.bellsouth.snt.cnmp.dao.csp.CspInputMarshallerTest.testGetUserRequest(CspInputMarshallerTest.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(Unknown Source)
... 26 more
```

**UPDATE: a manual workaround**
The missing jar file is jaxb-impl.jar It is in my class path included from the jars in the ear project. If I add jaxb-impl.jar in the classpath ahead of the default classpath. it runs fine.

In other project in my same workspace I do not have this issue.

Comment: No matter what you might think, `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory` is missing from your classpath.  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` never lies.

Comment: The class that you're missing is part of EclipseLink MOXy.  MOXy is an alternative implementation of JAXB.  Although it's part of the Eclipse family of projects, MOXy is distinct from the Eclipse IDE.  Did you [specify MOXy](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html) as your JAXB implementation using a jaxb.properties file?

Comment: @John R I did Not specify my jaxb implementation. I have no jaxb.properties file. perhaps that is my issue.

Comment: It's probably a classpath issue.  How are you building your project and where did you get the  jaxb-api.jar and jaxb-impl.jar that you're using?

Comment: I copied the jars from another project that a coworker created. I compiled the xsd with ant in eclipse. I am calling the code from a junit test.

Answer (score 2):

you may need the following dependencies, if you are using Maven,please refer to the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: maybe add an explanation, instead of an all code answer